# How is error in numerical methods defined (Big O notation, O(h))?

Tags: numerical-methods, truncation-error

I am trying to understand how the numerical method error is measured in O(h). In my understanding, the big O notation is depend on  the dominant term of equation, for example f(x)=x^2+x, the big O notation for this function is O(x^2).

But how is this related to numerical methods? Ever numerical methods I have seen has a big O notation of step size, for example(O(h),O(h^2)). How are these measured?

Thank you.

Comment: Please use the [search function](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=landau+notation+%22big+O%22), the Landau notation is often the topic. Which function is larger depends on where the limit is taken, $n\to\infty$ or $h\to 0$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Hi thank you so much for your reply! The link is super useful!